# How to reload webview in AppDelegate when tab is selected in ios

Tags: ios

im new in iOs development and  i cant solve this problem
how i can reload a uiwebview when i select a uitab here is my code:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)aTabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{

    if(self.tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0)
    {
        [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

        BSHomeViewController *homeViewController = [[BSHomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        BSHomeViewController.webView = nil;

        [BSHomeViewController.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:HOMEPAGE]]];


    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:self.tabBarController.selectedIndex forKey:@"BSSelectedTab"];
}
```

i declare it in appdelegate but it wont reload.

Please help me to solve this problem. All answers are much appreciated.

Comment: Where is located your webview ? In which view controller ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the AppDelegate as your tabbarcontroller's delegate.

You can do this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
```

I am not sure if this is proper design.

Why don't you reload the webview in BSHomeViewController's viewDidAppear?

Comment: thanks for your help, but i already did that i need to reload it every time i tap the uitab, for example when im in home tab when i tapped it again it supposed to reload again on same tab

Comment: what did you already do? set the delegate? or reload in viewDidAppear?

Comment: another related bug in your code: your web view is nil and you cannot send it a message.

Answer (score 0):

The code above is instantiating a new instance of BSHomeViewController when you call `BSHomeViewController *homeViewController = [[BSHomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];` and that view is never being displayed or pushed for the user to view. Is there a reason you're not choosing to leverage viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear when the UITabBar toggles to the selected ViewController?

EDIT: this is ugly but it will work...

TabBarDelegate.m

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)aTabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{

    if(self.tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0)
    {
            [viewController viewWillAppear:YES];
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:self.tabBarController.selectedIndex forKey:@"BSSelectedTab"];
}
```

BSHomeViewController.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:HOMEPAGE]]];
}
```

Comment: plus he's assigning nil to the webview and then asking to load the request

Comment: Thanks, it was a great help

Comment: I'm glad it helped. There are some more graceful ways of doing this but if you can live with quick & dirty it will work. Thanks for the pending solution checkmark. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Reload you webview every time you display BSHomeViewController's view

in your BSHomeViewController.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:HOMEPAGE]]];
}
```